# How to configure XAMPP's Mercury to send external mails?

Tags: php, mercury-mta

How to configure XAMPP's Mercury to send external mails using PHP's `mail()` but without any external SMTP account (such as smtp.gmail.com)? I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.zoe.vc/2008/configure-mercury-mail-for-external-mail/) but I guess it's probably outdated, because I still get error:

> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 553 We do not relay non-local
>   mail, sorry

I have always been using PHPMailer, but `mail()` method seems much lighter.

Comment: Many things could have gone wrong, can you show what the php.ini file looks like after those changes, i.e. the part that's related to the smtp etc.

Comment: mailToDisk and fakeMail disabled (commented), sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost, rest as default (localhost, port 25)

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck `Accept mail for invalid local address' in the Configuration of the     Mercury SMTP SERVER